# layout update fail when it is called in oncreat()method

Tags: android, layout

I have an issue with layout update. I have method like this :

```
public  void changeview(){
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    try{
        periodicCheck.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        periodiCheckText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        MessageDelayText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Error("set visibility failed: "+e);
    }
```

When I call the method from button 's click listener it works fine, but when I call the method within the oncreate() method of Acitivity class nothing happens.

I am just wondering maybe I need to refresh the layout but I am not sure?? I have tried to use invalidate mthod by implementing the following code, but still nothinf happens.

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById (R.id.main);
vg.invalidate();
```

I would appreciate any advice on that.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You must call this methods after setContentView();

Comment: Are you calling before setContentView()?

Comment: Thanks Guys, yes I am calling it after the setContentView() :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call this from the **onWindowFocusChanged()**. This is actually a abstract method of the Activity which will be called once your View is drawn. Override this to your Activity and check,

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
changeview();
super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}
```

Comment: thanks man, this one does the trick abit, but I have some tabs, which when I go to the other tabs again everything become visible.

Comment: Then call the method in changeview() onResume also

Comment: what do you mean exactly could you please give me sample? because I am using only one activity for tabs. does onResume detect layout change as well?